# How to unit test TagHelpers using just input and output?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

The following tests do work, but it seems silly to pass on all those object values as parameters instead of writing tests with just input and output parameters. In https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/test/ I only found similar test cases - There has to be some way to do this?

Test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyNamespace.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Shouldly;
using Xunit;

namespace MyNamespace.Tests
{
    public class ViewableTagHelperTests
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("<a href='#'>test</a>", "a", "a", true, null, "<a href='#'>test</a>")]
        [InlineData("<a href='#'>test</a>", "a", null, null, true, "")]
        [InlineData("<a href='#'>test</a>", "a", null, true, true, "")]
        [InlineData("<a href='#'>test</a>", "a", null, null, null, "")]
        [InlineData("<input href='#'/>", "input", "input", true, null, "<input href='#'/>")]
        [InlineData("<input href='#'/>", "input", null, null, true, "")]
        [InlineData("<input href='#'/>", "input", null, true, true, "")]
        [InlineData("<input href='#'/>", "input", null, null, null, "")]
        public void VerifyProperties(string input, string tag, string expectedTag, bool? show, bool? hide, string expectedOutput)
        {
            var viewableTagHelper = new ViewableTagHelper();
            var context = new TagHelperContext(tag, new TagHelperAttributeList
            {
                new TagHelperAttribute("display-if", show.HasValue ? show.Value ? "true" : "false" : "null"),
                new TagHelperAttribute("hide-if", hide.HasValue ? hide.Value ? "true" : "false" : "null"),
            }, new Dictionary<object, object>(), "1");
            var ouput = new TagHelperOutput(tag, new TagHelperAttributeList(), (b, encoder) =>
            {
                return Task.FromResult<TagHelperContent>(null);
            });

            ouput.Content.AppendHtml(input);
            viewableTagHelper.DisplayIf = show;
            viewableTagHelper.HideIf = hide;
            viewableTagHelper.Process(context, ouput);

            var content = ouput.Content.GetContent();

            content.ShouldBe(expectedOutput);
            ouput.TagName.ShouldBe(expectedTag);
        }
    }
}
```

TagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "hide-if")]
[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "display-if")]
public class ViewableTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("hide-if")]
    public bool? HideIf { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("display-if")]
    public bool? DisplayIf { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        bool diplay = true;
        if (diplay && HideIf.HasValue)
            diplay = !HideIf.Value;
        if (diplay && DisplayIf.HasValue)
            diplay = DisplayIf.Value;
        if (!DisplayIf.HasValue && !HideIf.HasValue)
            diplay = false;

        if (!diplay)
            output.SuppressOutput();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but it seems silly to pass on all those object values as parameters instead of writing tests with just input and output parameters`? can you clarify that part. It is a still unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You have to satisfy the dependency, which means mocking it up like you're doing. There's no way around that. What is your question here exactly?

Comment: @Nkosi it duplicates information which is technically present by passing an input string. If there were a way to infer those attribute values from string instead of manually setting the values on the property that would streamline the tests and make them easier to read